# "Always" vs. "forever"

Tags: meaning, differences, adverbs

What is the difference between *always* and *forever*? Are they synonyms used in different contexts or can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some contexts they mean the same, but differ syntactically...

> I will always love you. I will love you forever. /**not**/ ?I will forever love you. [1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/always)

In other contexts there's a difference in that *always* usually means *continuously, at all [relevant] times*, whereas *forever* usually means *for an infinite amount of time into the future*. Thus...

> He always catches the bus at 8am.  /**not**/ *He forever catches the bus at 8am.
>
> The universe may not last forever. /**not**/ ?The universe may not last always.

...where some people may find that last construction more acceptable than others.

Here's a useful summary of [usages for **always**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/always), only one or two of which overlap with [forever](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forever?s=t).

<sub>1: The song [I Will Forever Love You](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iu6sjNd0-hg) does exist, but it's nowhere near as well-known as [I Will Always Love You](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Will_Always_Love_You), written and first recorded by Dolly Parton, massively popularised by the late Whitney Houston.</sub>

Comment: "I will forever love you" sounds fine to me.

Comment: I agree with @Casey, and the O.P. "I will forever love you" sounds acceptable - but it also sounds markedly more flowery and poetic than the other two, so I agree there's a syntactic difference.

Comment: Well, if you say it, I can hardly assert that you don't. But you're well and truly in a minority - [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+love+you+forever%2Cwill+forever+love+you&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) says 25,900 written instances of *will love you forever* against 727 for *"will forever love you"*. The standard version is over 35 times more common, but the other one does exist - I'll change my * to a ?

Comment: Let me sleep on it

Comment: @Jim: You can always listen to *I'll forever love you* by [Mark Wills & Leanne Womack](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iu6sjNd0-hg) on youtube there. Personally, I can't stand that kind of music, and I don't like the grammar in that song either - but whatever floats your boat!

Comment: note the phrase _always and forever_ would be fluff if those two words didn't mean something different.

Comment: @Dan D.: To be honest I think *always and forever* actually **is** largely "fluff" ("**and forever**" adds about as much as "for ever **and ever**. Amen"). You could say *always* there means *on every occasion*, and *forever* means *for the infinite future*. But it's a bit like saying *aiding and abetting* are two distinct crimes - semantically/pedantically, a case can be made, but it doesn't amount to much.

Comment: Don't forget Donna Lewis' grammatically incorrect hit [I Love You Always Forever](http://www.lyrics007.com/Donna%20Lewis%20Lyrics/I%20Love%20You%20Always%20Forever%20Lyrics.html)

Answer (score 0):

*Always* generally refers to ongoing things while *forever* is a definitive way of saying that something will never end.

For example:

> - I *always* eat breakfast.
> - People have been eating breakfast *forever*.

Answer (score 0):

*Always*: This word can be used to refer to the current habit. Maybe it'll change or end in the future.

*Forever*: This word can be used to refer to the action which never ends in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd agree that there exist some syntactical difference but always and forever are the same based on a certain context:

1. The sun always rises from the east and sets in the west.
2. The sun shall, forever rise from the east and set in the west.

From (1) although its evident always is of an ongoing event or habit , its also not clear or certain when the event or habit may stop, it carries, concerns there might be some exceptions, but when? Its not certain, what time? - "all the time" -hence always.

Whereas in (2) its more evidently pronounced that the said event or habit continues in the future and shall certainly not stop.

In the context above , I would say Always and Forever are the same , because all the time, perpetual without certainty means perhaps ,

***the sun shall indeed for ever rise from the east and settle in the
west.***

Always transforms to forever at a point. Wherever always precedes a statement , forever is also intended for the future in most cases.